# Request.UrlReferrer throws null exception

Tags: url, c#-4.0, request

I have a web page 
say for ex:
http://mysite.com/index.aspx
and this page will be invoked from my client end which is a web application not sure about the platform! whether it could be c#, java, php or anything Say(http://myclient.com)

I need to get who is accessing my web page.

I tried URL Request.UrlReferrer but it is not working throws null exception.

Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're client is using secure connection (https) then url referrer will be null. Sorry this is not an answer to your question but just sharing as I can't comment as of now.